# What is an appropriate adjective to describe "beautifully bright" illuminations?

Tags: choix-de-mot

In conversation with a local Swiss resident, I used "éclatant" on the spur of the moment for lack of a better word:

> À force de voir tant d'illuminations des rues toutes les nuits, j'en oublierais que Saas-Fee est, à proprement parler, un village ! (rires) J’imagine que les décors durant la période de Noël y sont beaucoup plus ***éclatants*** et à ne pas manquer.

I wonder in hindsight if "éclatant" may have carried a negative connotation like "voyant" invariably does, suggesting (inadvertently, in my case) distastefully bright colours? Should I have said "***lumineux***" or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'adjectif **étincelant** est couramment associé aux décorations lumineuses de Noël. D'autres adjectifs peuvent bien sûr être utilisés :
-  **brillant** (qui est un peu moins lumineux qu'étincelant, mais si on emploie le verbe briller alors on peut l'amplifier en disant « briller de tous ses feux »),
-  **scintillant** (qui est associé à une lumière brillante mais tremblotante),
- **lumineux** peut bien sûr être utilisé, il est plus neutre et peut-être moins chargé de lumière (et de l'euphorie liée à Noël),
- **éclatant** peut être employé pour les décorations de Noël mais peut ne pas référer spécifiquement aux lumières, il peut aussi désigner la vivacité des couleurs, même non lumineuses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *brillants*. But *éclatants* feels right to me. I don't think it conveys a negative connotation, unless you really, really want to find irony in it.